# Fill multiple input fields after select an option from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, select, input, dropdown

I would like to create a dropdown menu with several options and when one selects an option, several input fields should be executed by it. Unfortunately I can't get the result I want. Can anyone help me with this? If possible with VanillaJS.

Thanks :)

```
<form>
    <select id="choice" name = "dropdown">
       <option id="AAPL">Apple</option>
       <option id="NKE">Nike</option>
       <option id="MCD">McDonalds</option>
    </select>
 </form>




var mydropdown = document.getElementById('choice');

mydropdown.onchange = function(){
     document.getElementById("Revenue1").value = 100
     document.getElementById("Revenue2").value = 100
     document.getElementById("Revenue3").value = 100
     document.getElementById("Revenue4").value = 100
     document.getElementById("Revenue5").value = 100


}
```

Comment: Your problem is on line 46.

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible sample, see how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please don't link to your code. Edit your question to include the most relevant parts of the code.

Comment: I would but I have no code for my problem

Comment: ???? How can you have a web page that isn't working correctly and not have any code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have no code for my problem because I don't know how to do it. Ive looked on google but did not found the right answer. I just want to implement a dropdown menu, where an option fills out a few input fields

Comment: I'm talking about posting the code that  you currently do have that isn't functioning as you want it to. Of course  you have that. Please read the minimal-reproducable-example link I posted above.

Comment: all of my code works well. Now I want to implement the dropdown menu. I posted some code which isn't working (and wrong, but I don't have any other)

Comment: "I can't get the result I want". You forgot to mention what result you want.

Comment: several input fields should be executed by values I've added

Comment: Define "execute". Your question is currently unanswerable as it's not clear enough.

Comment: if someone uses my calculation model, he should get a dropdown list with e.g. Apple, Nike, McDonalds etc.. If he then clicks on Apple, 5 different input fields should automatically fill in with values stored in the code. I would like to use only html and VanillaJS if possible :) Sorry, I'm new and can not express myself well

Comment: my code example above works fine but It doesn't matter which value I choose, it always fills the fields with "100". I know why it is wrong but I don't know how to solve it :-D

Comment: You've hardcoded your dropdown's `onchange` to populate with 100; what should they populate with instead?

Comment: They should remain hardcoded and I set them myself. The problem is that no matter which option I click on (Apple, Nike, McDonald), the values are always 100. But each option should get its own values

Comment: If you want them to be different based on the option selected, they cannot remain hardcoded. What values should those be and how are you storing those values?

Comment: These are supposed to be the cash flows. My plan was to simply create them in JS as variables.

Comment: In that case, you'd just use those JS variables instead of 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydropdown.onchange = function(){
    switch(this.value){
    case"Apple":
        document.getElementById("Revenue1").value = 100;
        document.getElementById("Revenue2").value = 100;
        document.getElementById("Revenue3").value = 100;
        document.getElementById("Revenue4").value = 100;
        document.getElementById("Revenue5").value = 100;
        break;
        case"Nike":
        document.getElementById("Revenue1").value = 200;
        document.getElementById("Revenue2").value = 200;
        document.getElementById("Revenue3").value = 200;
        document.getElementById("Revenue4").value = 200;
        document.getElementById("Revenue5").value = 200;
        break;
    case"McDonalds":
        document.getElementById("Revenue1").value = 400;
        document.getElementById("Revenue2").value = 500;
        document.getElementById("Revenue3").value = 400;
        document.getElementById("Revenue4").value = 400;
        document.getElementById("Revenue5").value = 400;
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("Revenue1").value = 4000;
        document.getElementById("Revenue2").value = 5000;
        document.getElementById("Revenue3").value = 4000;
        document.getElementById("Revenue4").value = 4000;
        document.getElementById("Revenue5").value = 4000;
        break;
  }
}
```